# How To Get Only One Restaurant When I Press Click Button One Click item listener

Tags: android

I have app in side it only one activity (main activity) and layout XML of main activity have only 
list view .this app get restaurants near from my location and display it in list view 
What i need to do is add button to the main activity layout when i press on button get to me list of restaurant item by item
from json file and display it in list view but not display all restaurants in one click but show item by item
every click get restaurant
suppose i have 3 restaurant in json file
when i click on button for first click get me first restaurant
when i click on button for second click get me second restaurant
when i click on button for third click get me third restaurant 
How to customize this code to accept get item by item restaurant from json file
My code include class and activity and code is working success 
my class is FoursquareVenue

```
package com.foodsmap_project_app.foodsmap_project_app;
public class FoursquareVenue
{
private String name;
private String city;

private String category;

public FoursquareVenue() {
this.name = "";
this.city = "";
this.setCategory("");
}

public String getCity() {
if (city.length() > 0) {
return city;
}
return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
if (city != null) {
this.city = city.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "");
;
}
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public String getCategory() {
return category;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
this.category = category;
}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    ArrayList<FoursquareVenue> venuesList;
    Button btn;
    int clickCount;

 //   ArrayList<FoursquareVenue> allResults;

    List<String> shownResults = new ArrayList<String>();

    //final String CLIENT_ID = "1CO3ZGVRFHXUIKWGFGDJBLJS4DNKX25EBR1TVEYSEUOFKCJD";
    //final String CLIENT_SECRET = "P24DH3AUZUW4Q3Q1WHLG4HED0WPPMHT4P30TOKG2EFWAJPIJ";
   // final String latitude = "30.435665153239377";
   // final String longtitude = "31.144435908398464";
   final String CLIENT_ID = "SVIBXYYXOEARXHDI4FWAHXGO5ZXOY204TCF1QJFXQLY5FPV4";
    final String CLIENT_SECRET = "BAAJO1KXRWESGTJJGVON4W3WUFHAQDAJPLRIYJJ5OPHFQ5VI";
   final String latitude = "30.435665153239377";
   final String longtitude = "31.3280148";
    ArrayAdapter <String> myAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       new fourquare().execute();
        btn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                String name = venuesList.get(clickCount).getName();

                String cat = venuesList.get(clickCount).getCategory();

                String city = venuesList.get(clickCount).getCity();

                shownResults.add(name + "," + "cat" + "" + city);

                clickCount++;

                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                new fourquare().execute();

            }
        });

    }
    private class fourquare extends AsyncTask<View, Void, String> {

        String temp;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(View... urls) {

           //temp = makeCall("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret=" + CLIENT_SECRET + "&v=20130815&ll=30.435665153239377,31.144435908398464");
            temp = makeCall("https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=" + CLIENT_ID + "&client_secret=" + CLIENT_SECRET + "&v=20130815&ll=30.435665153239377,31.144435908398464" + "&query=resturant");
            //public static String URL_GET_Place = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id=SVIBXYYXOEARXHDI4FWAHXGO5ZXOY204TCF1QJFXQLY5FPV4&client_secret=BAAJO1KXRWESGTJJGVON4W3WUFHAQDAJPLRIYJJ5OPHFQ5VI&v=20130815&ll=30.1136286,31.3280148&query=resturant";

            return "";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (temp == null) {

            } else {

                venuesList = (ArrayList<FoursquareVenue>) parseFoursquare(temp);

                List<String> listTitle = new ArrayList<String>();

                for (int i = 0; i < venuesList.size(); i++) {

                    listTitle.add(i, venuesList.get(i).getName() + ", " + venuesList.get(i).getCategory() + "" + venuesList.get(i).getCity());
                }


                myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row_layout, R.id.listText, listTitle);
                setListAdapter(myAdapter);
            }
        }
    }
    public static String makeCall(String url) {


        StringBuffer buffer_string = new StringBuffer(url);
        String replyString = "";


        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(buffer_string.toString());

        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();


            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(20);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            replyString = new String(baf.toByteArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return replyString.trim();
    }
    private static ArrayList<FoursquareVenue> parseFoursquare(final String response) {

        ArrayList<FoursquareVenue> temp = new ArrayList<FoursquareVenue>();
        try {


            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);


            if (jsonObject.has("response")) {
                if (jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").has("venues")) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("venues");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        FoursquareVenue poi = new FoursquareVenue();
                        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("name")) {
                            poi.setName(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));

                            if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("location")) {
                                if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").has("address")) {
                                    if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").has("city")) {
                                        poi.setCity(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("location").getString("city"));
                                    }
                                    if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).has("categories")) {
                                        if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("categories").length() > 0) {
                                            if (jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("categories").getJSONObject(0).has("icon")) {
                                                poi.setCategory(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("categories").getJSONObject(0).getString("name"));
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    temp.add(poi);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ArrayList<FoursquareVenue>();
        }
        return temp;

    }

}
```

Comment: where is Buttan in this code

Comment: r u able to see the list on item

Comment: Please try to use punctuation (.) in your question. It is really hard (nearly impossible) for me to understand what you are asking.

Comment: sorry i edit my post now with Onitemclick listner

Comment: all code working without problem only button click not working

Comment: Can any one help me answering this question

Comment: What is not clear in my code above

Comment: why no respond with my post every thing is clear

Comment: This lines of code that have proplem